# Does a Gilbert cell have automatic gain control?

Tags: mosfet, ac, gilbert-cell

Just wondering, I need to demonstrate that it does have automatic gain control for  project... paranoid me just wants to make sure!

Answer (score 1):

A Gilbert Cell doesn't *have* AGC.

You can use a Gilbert Cell as an analogue multiplier. It can multiply one signal using the other as a scale factor.

If you follow a Gilbert Cell with a level detector, and take a control loop back to the scale factor input, then you can *build* an AGC.

Answer (score 0):

Gilbert multiplying cell uses bipolar base-emitter junction to convert to-from log(Vin), with the scale-factor being adjustable.

So, yes, you can use the scale-factor fro AGC.

Examine the MC1496 schematic for the full implementation.